# how to improve quality of skeleton made with medial_axis

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to make a skeleton of an image using medial_axis but for some reason, the result comes out really messy

does anyone have an idea how could I improve it?

I also tried using skeletonize and the skeleton itself seems better but it isn't quite what I'm looking for.

[image: Base image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis

def Get_binary(image):    
    thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
    binary = image > thresh
    return binary


def Skeletonize_img():

    im = Get_binary(imread('image_bin.png'))
    im_ax = medial_axis(im)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True,
                        figsize=(8,8))

    ax = axes.ravel()

    ax[0].imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax[0].set_title('binary image')
 
    ax[1].imshow(im_ax, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax[1].set_title('medial axis')
    

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()  


Skeletonize_img()
```

[image: Result]

[image: Result2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from skimage import img_as_bool, io, color, morphology
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = img_as_bool(color.rgb2gray(io.imread('image_bin.png')))
out = morphology.medial_axis(image)

f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.imshow(out, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

**Also adding black border around the image will help**